# Eclipse ADT version 21 plugin , fail to compile working workspace "no targets available” when everything correctly setup

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have problem with compiling workspace fully functional after Update to ADT 2.1 , after some eclipse restarts and cannot find any mention about it anywhere. I am running Mac OS X Mountain Lion and I also tried to use Eclipse installation coming bundled with latest ADT 21. Problem is still repeating. It seems to me as bug.

In Android preferences of Eclipse there is message “No targets available” even thou folder is correctly setup to correct SDK.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40242

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it toke mi almost two hours to find working solution for this bug. I reinstalled everything tried to go back to ADT 20 and then accidentally upgraded tools and again was forced to update ADT to 21 that is failing for me…

Solution is simply to have two correct Android SDK folders and you have to point eclipse to other folder, apply, it loads SDK correctly than you can go back to SDK you actually use and everything works. Well till next restart and yo have to do it again . Thank you Android developers , each new big update , new big bug on osx :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another option (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14045656/4100), if you did disable the android plugin from running at startup, this will happen. Enabling it should fix the bug.