# ADT does not load target platforms even if they are installed. How to Fix?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

**Symptoms:**

I encountered this problem when I was creating a new Android Application project in eclipse.

I was not allowed to go past the first screen of the new project wizard because of "A package name cannot start or end with a dot"

- Application name: Lahari
- Project name: Lahari App
- Package name: com.example.lahari
- Minimum required SDK: API8: Android 2.2(Froyo)
- Target SDK: API16: Android 4.1(Jelly Bean)
- Compile with: (No option to select)
- theme: Holo Light

So I started googling around and tried a lot solutions from SO and other sites.

> One of the associated problem (which I hadn't realized) was that
>   Target Platforms list was empty, the last time I tried it had loaded
>   fine but not anymore.

SDK Manager said platforms were installed and up to date.
No updates were there for ADT, SDK Tools, or Eclipse.

***Problem:***

In Eclipse, Windows > Tools > Preferences > Android the path was set properly but no targets would load.

***My System configuration is:***

- Win 7 64 bit - all updates applied to date
- Eclipse Juno SR1 (up to date)
- ADT 21.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried all the solutions on the web. It took me a day's time to find the working solution.

***So here's the solution:***

> **DISABLE YOUR ANTIVIRUS!**

***Antivirus I'm using:***

Kaspersky Internet Security 2013

This was the least expected of solutions, I know.

I chanced upon this while I was about to re-install SDK.

***Update***: This solution failed to work on another system.
So this is what worked.

> ***1) In eclipse, Go to windows->preferences->startup and shutdown->check***
> ***android ADT***
>
> ***2) Restart eclipse***

I used to disable all the things in startup and shutdown as this used to make eclipse much much faster. This never created a problem before.

However all is well again ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Enabling "windows->preferences->startup and shutdown->android development toolkit" really helps.